# how to filter list in angular

Tags: angular

I  have a list of items(listUsers), and I want to  filter the list. but  it doesn't work. I Wonder if my method was correct or not?

this was the html file:

```
<div class="search-div">
  <mat-form-field class="search-form-field" floatLabel="never" style="display: flex;`justify-content: center;">
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="searchKey" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" (keyup)="applyFilter()">
  <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchKey" (click)="onSearchClear()">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-selection-list >
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let d of listUsers" >{{d.username}}</mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

this was the .ts file

```
listUsers: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getAll()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.listUsers = data;
      console.log(this.listUsers);
    });
}

onSearchClear() {
  this.searchKey = '';
}

applyFilter(value: string) {
  this.listUsers.filter = this.searchKey.trim().toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not "angular filter function" but javascript array filter function. You need to pass a callback.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Example:

```
this.listUsers = this.listUsers.filter(user => user === condition)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a type of text search you can combine `.filter()` and `.includes()` function of vanila JavaScript to find users which are similar to the search text.

```
this.listUsers = this.listUsers.filter(u => u.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase())
```